# ASP.NET MVC Button.Click Not working with javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, button

I have a form that requires user input with two buttons: one button to `submit` the form values and the other button is to load a `partial view`. I'm not sure if my approach here is correct though. The `submit` button works perfectly fine however clicking the button with `GenerateBtn` id does not fire the `DisplayProposal()` function that loads the `partial view`. Any idea to solve or a better approach??

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Proposal</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.item, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.item, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
    </div>

    <h2>Generated Questions</h2>
    <div id="ProposalTable"></div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="button" value="Generate" class="btn btn-default" id="GenerateBtn" />
    </div>
</div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

<script>
    document.getElementById("GenerateBtn").onclick = function () { DisplayProposal() };
    function DisplayProposal() {
        //Loads Partial View to <div>ProposalTable</div>
        $('ProposalTable').load('@Url.Action("LoadStuff", "Proposals")');
    }

</script>
```

}

Comment: add `ClientIDMode = "Static"` in `<input type="button"`

Comment: try to put the document.getElementById line after the function definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason you aren't using jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#GenerateBtn").click(function(){
       DisplayProposal();
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @MikeS It works perfectly fine! Any Reason why this works instead of the code above?

Comment: Not off the top of my head. does document.getElementById("GenerateBtn") return anything?